# Oracle sql select data from table where attribute is nested table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, nested-table

I have a objects:

```
create type t_history_rec is object
(
  date_from date,
  current float
);

create type t_history is table of t_history_rec;
```

and table defined:

```
create table person
(
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar2(30),
  history t_history

);
```

and I want to get select name, history.date_from, history.current like this:

```
name1 date1 current1
name1 date2 current2
name2 date3 current3
...
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors. `current` is reserved

```
create or replace type t_history_rec is object
(
  date_from date,
  curr float
);
/
create type t_history is table of t_history_rec;
/
```

Table definition needs `store as`

```
create table person
(
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar2(30),
  history t_history
) NESTED TABLE history STORE AS col1_tab;

insert into person (id, name, history) values (1, 'aa', t_history(t_history_rec(sysdate, 1)));
insert into person (id, name, history) values (2, 'aa', t_history(t_history_rec(sysdate, 1), t_history_rec(sysdate, 1)));
```

Then select is:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.date_from, t2.curr FROM person t1, TABLE(t1.history) t2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Cannot verify this, but you could try something like this:

```
select p.name, pp.date_from, pp.current 
from person p, table(p.history) pp;
```